# Custom application icons not displaying

Tags: icons

I am working on a package for a custom application and cannot get my applications icons to display. Here is my desktop file, which is installed in `/usr/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Map Creator
Icon=ntfmo-map-creator
TryExec=/opt/ntfmo/map_creator/bin/map_creator
Exec=/opt/ntfmo/map_creator/bin/map_creator.sh
Categories=Office;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.16
```

I have copied images to the following locations:

- /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/ntfmo-map-creator.png
- /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/ntfmo-map-creator.png
- /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/ntfmo-map-creator.svg

I have rebooted, but still nothing. Do you have to register the icons or something?

**[EDIT]** Ok, I got it to work by running `sudo rm -f /usr/share/icons/*/icon-theme.cache`, but that seems a little draconian. Is that the "correct" solution? Does my package need to run that after it installs? Seems a little much....

Comment: I think you are supposed to call gtk-update-icon-cache as per http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gtk-update-icon-cache.1.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor` to your `debian/postinst` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor

exit 0
```

Comment: OK, thanks, this is working. Although I also noticed that ubuntu automatically updates the cache when icons are added as part of a package, but not when you manually drop them in.

Comment: gtk-update-icon-cache checks the timestamp on the top-level icon directory, so you also need to `touch` that. The only documentation I can find for this is here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#Icon_Cache

Comment: Wow....8 years later and this worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you!