# Activate dash after minimal GUI installation on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, bash, gui

I installed the ubuntu desktop package without recommends on Ubuntu server 12.04 and noticed that dash does not work - it just won't find any applications ([screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/a9041ho3x/)). How can I activate it? I assume that some required packages were not installed (on the other hand, dependencies are always checked...). Appriciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, since you did a minimal install, you don't have any of the scopes and lens that come by default in unity. If you look at the bottom of your dash, it only shows the home dash, not any applications, files, music... etc options.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications
```

And then log out and log in again.

You can also install unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos... etc if you need them.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Gotta love Stack Exchange and its community :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `apt-get install gnome-terminal`

That should do the trick.

Update:

It might be related to the icon cache. Take a look at [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64283/custom-application-icons-not-displaying) answer.
My guess it that the `highcolor-icon-theme` package is missing or messed up.

Comment: The terminal is installed as Ctr+Alt+T starts it. No matter what I type in bash (even update or firefox), it doesn't show any search results.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I've been thinking for a while about doing the same, building ubuntu from a minimal install... but too lazy xD Cheers