# Custom application icon does not appear

Tags: icons

My application's icon is not showing if I do not use an absolute path like here:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyProgram
GenericName=MyProgram
Comment=This is a comment
Icon=/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/MyProgram/Icons/myprogram.svg
Exec=myprogram
Categories=Utility;TextTools;
Hidden=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Instead I write

```
Icon=myprogram
```

just like I call the program with `Exec=myprogram`, where it searches under `/usr/bin`.

According to the [free desktop standards](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) I copied the icons to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor` and even deleted the icon-cache as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64283/custom-application-icons-not-displaying) with `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor`. Still my icon does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a full path, icons must reside inside the current icon scheme location.

If you want to add a program icon that is not part of any specific scheme, put it in `/usr/share/icons/`.

Comment: i did copy them to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor`as i said. According to the docs this is the very last directory where is searched for icons. It has to work, but does not. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution as described in question, plus what I did by accident:

Somehow my launcher and panel disappeared and I restored them with

```
#!/bin/bash
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons
```

Then my icons worked. Should be easier...